# Can I install different versions of CUDA toolkit and PyTorch?

Tags: python, installation, pytorch

If my CUDA version is 11.2 with PyTorch CUDA version 10.2, will it cause a problem if I later install NVIDIA CUDA toolkit 11.3?

Comment: It depends how you installed pytorch and cuda. If you installed pytorch through pip or conda then pytorch uses its own copy of the cuda library delivered with torch and never sees the system cuda (you don't need to have cuda installed on your system in this case). If you compiled pytorch from source then your pytorch library likely links against the system cuda so changing your toolkit version will cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

no you can not do this.
the libcudnn version need corresponding to correct cuda version

try to use cuda 11.3 for pytorch
look this answer: [I can't train my NN with TensorFlow using GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70306845/i-cant-train-my-nn-with-tensorflow-using-gpu)