# I can't train my NN with TensorFlow using GPU

Tags: python, gpu, tensorflow2.0

My first ever Deep Learning project (computer vision - Diabetic retinopathy).

I'm trying to run my experiments using my GPU (NVidia RTX 3050).

I followed the attached tutorial https://shawnhymel.com/1961/how-to-install-tensorflow-with-gpu-support-on-windows/ to install Cuda and cudNN to enable TensorFlow with GPU.

IDE: PyCharm 2021.3

Interpreter: Python 3.9 (conda)

TensorFlow version for Python 3.9 GPU support: https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-2.7.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl

code:

```py
    print(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices())

    train_df, valid_df, test_df = get_dataset.get_datasets()
    trainGen, valGen, testGen = data_gen.get_data_generators(train_df, valid_df, test_df, image_size=IMAGE_SIZE, BS=32)
    with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
        model = model.get_model(image_size=299, model_type='InceptionV3_att')  # 'InceptionV3' \ 'InceptionV3_att' \
    # 'DenseNet121'

        model.compile(
            optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),  # by default learning_rate=0.001
            loss='categorical_crossentropy',
            metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(name="cat_acc"), tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc'),
                    tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall'), tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
                    tfa.metrics.CohenKappa(num_classes=5, sparse_labels=False, weightage='quadratic')]
        )
        model.summary()
        # keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)

        history = model.fit(
            trainGen,
            epochs=NUM_EPOCHS,
            steps_per_epoch=len(train_df) // BS,
            validation_data=valGen,
            validation_steps=len(valid_df) // BS,
            class_weight={0: len(train_df[train_df['Label'] == '0']) / len(train_df),
                          1: len(train_df[train_df['Label'] == '1']) / len(train_df),
                          2: len(train_df[train_df['Label'] == '2']) / len(train_df),
                          3: len(train_df[train_df['Label'] == '3']) / len(train_df),
                          4: len(train_df[train_df['Label'] == '4']) / len(train_df)},
            shuffle=True,
            callbacks=[
                # tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=11, verbose=1),
                tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(patience=4, verbose=1),
                tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath='bestmodel.h5', save_best_only=True, verbose=1)]
        )
```

I can't train my model unless I'm using CPU

```
with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
```

getting this output:

```
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

> 

**2021-12-10 17:10:52.291326: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.**

**2021-12-10 17:10:53.019482: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1671 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Laptop GPU, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6**

Epoch 1/20

**2021-12-10 17:11:00.077237: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:366] Loaded cuDNN version 8301**

**Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)**

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68546140/cant-train-with-gpu-in-tensorflow) answer to yours?

Comment: I just had a very similar issue and Marte's thread indeed helped me (thank you!): I had installed CUDA and cudnn alright but had overlooked the part about zlibwapi.dll in https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html. The lack of this DLL was causing exactly the symptoms mentioned by the OP. Instead of using the obsolete pre-built binary served over an insecure connection, I rebuilt the DLL from the latest zlib 1.2.11 source release, using the SLN in contrib/vsstudio/vc14 and just dropped the resulting binary in my c:/dev/cudnn/bin folder already in the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

```
ASUS Dual GeForce RTX 3050 OC  

NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-510.47.03.run (location:Data Center/Tesla)  
cuda_11.3.1_465.19.01_linux.run  
libcudnn8_8.2.1.32-1+cuda11.3_amd64.deb  
libcudnn8-dev_8.2.1.32-1+cuda11.3_amd64.deb  
libcudnn8-samples_8.2.1.32-1+cuda11.3_amd64.deb  
pip3 install torch==1.11.0+cu113 torchvision==0.12.0+cu113 torchaudio==0.11.0+cu113 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html  

installed and test PPO-AI in cuda OK  
I think it's fit to tensorflow too  
you can try these files install and test again   

if you wan to uninstall current cuda  
sudo /usr/local/cuda-X.Y/bin/cuda-uninstaller
```

Cuda and Corresponding driver
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html
drivers
https://www.nvidia.com/download/find.aspx
all cuda version
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive